# Scala SBT project error happens while execute run

Tags: mysql, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, quill

I'm doing **Scala** **SBT** project using **mySQL** and **quill** in **intellij idea community**
when I'm run my project using `sbt run` command in terminal, it gives following error messages.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$1 (file:/tmp/sbt_ca022510/target/fc3580dd/177fa64e/netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

But execution result also receive. (Example as when I run a method for insert data to a table, data have insert the table while error displaying)

I search this error and "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" in google. But I couldn't find about it. All I want to know, what is the error message and will it impact to my result anyway.

Comment: That's not error but warn, and doesn't mean there is anything wrong as long as it builds

Comment: Can you share your build.sbt?

Comment: name := "quill_example"

version := "0.1"

//scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "io.getquill" %% "quill-async-mysql" % "3.4.10",
 "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.17",
// "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-slf4j-impl" % "2.1" % Test
)

this is my "build.sbt" file